# Alguém sabe como posso atribuir uma borda em um triangulo feito com css?

Tags: css

O código é esse:

```css
div {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 40px 30px 40px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
}
```

```html
<div/>
```

Eu quero criar uma borda nele.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer um triângulo dentro de outro:

```css
.triangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 44px 34px 44px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
}
.inner-triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: -38px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 38px 28px 38px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #f09 transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
  <div class="inner-triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu quero colocar uma borda no left e right mas no bottom não, olha como ta a imagem http://imgur.com/a/HyPw9

Comment: @OtavioFagundes, olhe a minha edição. Era assim que queria?

Comment: exatamente isso, agora sim, vlw